# Redirect in Javascript with data (laravel 5.3)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, redirect

I have to redirect on edit page with its data if user clicks on save button 
here is my button:

```
<button type="submit" name="edit" class="btn green" value="edit">Save</button>
```

When user click this button i get name of button here in update controller as

```
return $request->input('edit');
```

this return goes in to js file

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result == 'save_add') {
        window.location = "/student-management/list/create"
    } else if (result == 'edit') {
        window.location = "////////////////////////////"
    }else {
         window.location = "/student-management/list"
    }
}
```

route is

```
route('student.edit')
```

Here i am redirecting user to its actual path in case of edit on 2nd else if i want to redirect on edit page with its data 
i am working same here with other page in controller but i want to do this in js

```
if(Input::get('save_add')) {
    return redirect()->route('student.create');
} elseif(Input::get('edit')) {
    return redirect()->route('student.edit', ['id' => $id ]);
} else {
    return redirect()->route('student.index');
}
```

I want to send same as above id with that redirect for edit

Comment: It's not clear what your asking for help with.

Comment: @Joe dear i am asking to redirect page with id from js file where i have /////////////////////////// in my question  as i am  `return redirect()->route('student.edit', ['id' => $id ]);  here

Comment: does javascript know the id? what does the edit url look like -- how is the id passed in the url?

Comment: i am getting id just tell me please how to pass edit route in windows.location

Comment: I don't know what the edit url is, so not sure how to answer that fully correctly

Comment: are going to post data while listing, saving and editing to a same function..... if(Input::get('save_add')){...} this code seems like that... this is not a good way for getting things done in laravel5.3

Comment: return redirect()->route('student.edit', ['id' => $id ]); - do you have this url, i think student.edit is a view and route('') looks for url that is written in route.php file rather than viewpath

Comment: student.edit is to show the edit form

Comment: and i also want to pass student.edit route with window.location

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your JavaScript already knows the user's id in a variable called `id`, and the edit url to send to takes the form of `/student-management/student/{id}`:

```
window.location = "/student-management/student/" + id
```

Comment: how to pas this route to window.location route('student.edit', ['id' => $id ]);

Comment: I don't know what you mean. the above code will call that url, with the id in the proper spot

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

In your controller

```
return return response()->json(['success'=>true,'result'=>$request->input('edit'),'url'=> route('student.edit', ['id' => $id ])]);
```

Your js

```
success:: function(data)
{
 if(data.success)
  {  
      window.location = data.url
  }
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: how to pas this route to window.location `route('student.edit', ['id' => $id ]);`

Comment: what is data.url in window.location

Comment: url is key of json data you are returning in response. 'url'=> route('student.edit', ['id' => $id ]).  there was a small typo in the response i was returning . i corrected that